# calc does not calculate width

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which I have 4 columns:

```
column 1: fixed width of 500px;
column 2: calc(33% - 165px);
column 3: calc(33% - 165px);
column 4: calc(33% - 165px);
```

Having same value on last 3 columns, the width of those columns is different.

Here is my html:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 500px;">Vishal</td>
      <td style="width: calc(33% - 165px); background: #ff0000;">Sherathiya</td>
      <td style="width: calc(33% - 165px); background: #ffff00;">28</td>
      <td style="width: calc(33% - 165px); background: #ff00ff;">edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Seema</td>
      <td>Kaneria</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nikunj</td>
      <td>Ramani</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>delete</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is css:

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the codepen that reproduces the issue:

https://codepen.io/Vishal1419/pen/aqOErL

**Solution:**

I had to have `table-layout: fixed`. Also, I had to apply styles for header as well. So, now

my html looks like:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 500px;">First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 500px;">Vishal</td>
      <td class="field">Sherathiya</td>
      <td class="field">28</td>
      <td class="field">edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Seema</td>
      <td>Kaneria</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nikunj</td>
      <td>Ramani</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>delete</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and css:

table{
   table-layout:fixed;
   width: 100%;
}

.field {
  width: calc(33% - 165px);
  background: #ff0000;
}

Answer (score -1):

Just use css and give them classes:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}

.field {
  width: calc(33% - 165px);
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td style="width: 500px;">Vishal</td>
  <td class="field">Sherathiya</td>
  <td class="field">28</td>
  <td class="field">edit</td>
```

Comment: does not work at all. Try it on codepen.

Comment: Check this out:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvpvrN

Comment: Your codepen is constantly refreshing.

Comment: Works fine for me